# Unclear regex expression in Java

Tags: java, regex, string

```
x=x.replaceFirst("(?<=^.)\\S+", ".")
```

I found this in program and I dont't understand what does that do. Could someone explain this to me, please?

Comment: Can you take a look at the doc about Java regex?

Comment: Specifically at lookarounds and metacharacters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It basically trims the first word, except its first letter. 
Here is its desription:

```
(?<=^.) Positive Lookbehind - assert that the regex below can be matched

   ^ assert position at start of the string

   . matches any character (except newline)

\\S  match any non-white space character ( not like [\r\n\t\f ])

   +    between one and unlimited times
```

you can read the description [here](https://regex101.com/r/oC0rU5/2)